# MySQL: server returns records in wrong encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding, collation

I have DB in the cp1251_general_ci encoding (there are some historical reasons for it). All things were perfect till I have changed a hoster.
Now I faced a problem. Their server returns records by query in utf-8.
I want to solve this problem right not to touch HTML-output. So I see such the way - to force a server to give content just in cp1251_general_ci.
I guess the point is a MySQL connection collation. If so I presume next things:
1. Copy current DB to point MySQL connection collation AS cp1251_general_ci. After that use this DB and delete source DB.
   OR
2. Add to the DB-queries **COLLATION**.
If it's right/wrong or you have the way better I will glad to hear your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your terrific answers! :)
In order to solve the problem I have made own investigation.
Here is a solution:

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='cp1251'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='cp1251'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='cp1251_general_ci'");
```

So the point is to force a sever to set a proper encoding during a query/answer. Now it works perfectly.